# I deleted files from my Linux box's /boot directory and now it won't boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, boot, grub

I did that to save space.

Now I see GRUB loading, please wait ... ERROR 15

on boot.

/boot still has files corresponding to 2.6.32-27 version of Linux. But I deleted all others that did not have that string in /boot

What can I do ?

Comment: Restore from the backup you hopefully made before doing something like this? You wouldn't remove two wheels from your car "to make it lighter" then be all surprised when it doesn't drive properly would you?

Comment: @Robert I think this is more like removing the transmission, no? :)

Comment: @vortaq7, it's most like removing the starter, the engine will keep running until you turn it off, then you're screwed.

Comment: @Chris that's a better analogy.

Comment: Most people don't do something like removing the starter or engine. I've known people that would probably remove a tire or two and wonder why they can't drive it up the driveway without a problem. I've SEEN people driving with complete flats a few miles just to get a little farther and wonder why it cost them more to replace the rims afterwards.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First the lecture:

Rule Number Zero: If you do not understand what something does, **DO NOT TOUCH IT**
Deleting files "to save space" with no concept of what you are doing will anger the operating system gods, resulting problems similar to what you are now experiencing (Things break. Fixing them is often non-trivial).

---

Now the sympathetic assistance:

Fortunately you have not destroyed the universe: Fixing this particular problem is relatively trivial.  Locate an appropriate boot CD (your Ubuntu install disk should be usable as a LiveCD) and run `grub-install` with appropriate parameters to re-install the files `grub` is looking for in your `/boot` directory (you may want to google around for further information).
You will also need to `dpkg-reconfigure grub` to rebuild the grub menu and various other bits and pieces you may have blown away.

---

I have intentionally left this answer somewhat vague, pointing you in the right direction rather than giving you line-by-line commands - you can get all the gory details of what to type and why from the internet.
A little legwork is often good for the soul, and will increase your understanding of the Linux boot process...

Comment: I burnt a live cd and used these instructions. Thanks !! http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099

Comment: @abc - Yup, those will do the job :)

Comment: +1 for pointing and not telling